# salesforce python Beatbox import error

Tags: python, soap, salesforce, python-3.4, beatbox

I am trying to log in to salesforce.com's sandbox using a URL, ID and PASS. I want to use SOAP API for that. When I try to import beatbox in python3, it throws an ImportError exception. However, I can confirm that beatbox is installed in python3. So what am I doing wrong? Is there any other way to do it?

```
Python 3.5.0 (default, Dec  6 2015, 17:23:12) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import beatbox
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/beatbox-32.1-py3.5.egg/beatbox/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named '_beatbox'
>>>
```

Comment: In the python prompt type: `help("modules")`. This would give you all the modules installed. Use grep to filter what you don't need.

Comment: help('modules') confirmed beatbox is installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The beatbox module that you probably installed is this : [Beatbox 32.1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beatbox).

**Solution 1 :** The above beatbox module only supports python 2.x (tested with python 2.7). So, switch to Python 2.x if that is an option.

You can find the source by original author of beatbox [here](https://github.com/superfell/Beatbox) and it has been updated to support python3.

**Solution 2 :**

- Clone the repo in your local machine using `git clone https://github.com/superfell/Beatbox.git`
- Change to the Beatbox directory
- Install the module using `python setup.py install`

Comment: actually the pypi beatbox module source is at https://github.com/davisagli/beatbox

Comment: Oh, my bad. Your name was there as the Author, so i thought it was you. It probably meant the original author of source code. No wonder I was confused about a comment in an issue of your repo about putting the code in pypi. I'll make changes to my answer. Thanks for pointing it out @superfell.

Comment: Have anybody tried download a report using beatbox? My entire solution is built on beatbox and I am now trying to download a report and failing to do so due to weird html error. @superfell

Comment: @r0xette Ask another question with the error you are getting. That way you'll get a better response.

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was I had both beatbox and beatbox3 installed.
beatbox3  is the version for python3.

Once I uninstalled beatbox it worked fine.